# How to enable RBAC automatically

Tags: linux, grsec, rbac

I think I'm missing something simple, but every time I try to `gradm -E`, I'm being asked for a password. How can I enable it automatically after boot? (so that no password is needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an init.d script.

Something containing:

```
start)  log_daemon_msg "Starting grsecurity ACL control" "gradm "
    /sbin/gradm -E
```

Comment: Ok, I'm just tired. I thought I got the password question on both `-E` and `-D`, but it's only when disabling.